# Borrar un registro teniendo tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Necesito borrar el `idcliente`, `nombre` y `apellido` de la tabla `cliente`, pero no me deja borrarlo porque está relacionado con la tabla `ubicacion`. Para eso, también quiero ir eliminando todos los registros de ese id de cliente en todas las tablas.

Esta es la estructura de las tablas:

```
create table cliente(
    idcliente    varchar(50) primary key,
    nombre       varchar(50),
    apellido     varchar(50)
)

create table ubicacion(
    idubicacion  varchar(50) primary key,
    pais         varchar(50),
    ciudad       varchar(50),
    fkcliente    varchar(50)
)

create table venta(
    idproducto   varchar(50),
    producto     varchar(50),
    fkubicacion  varchar(50)
)

alter table ubicacion 
  add constraint fkcliente_idcliente
  foreign key (fkcliente) references cliente(idcliente)

alter table venta
  add constraint fkubicacion_idubicacion
  foreign key (fkubicacion) references ubicacion(idubicacion)
```

Comment: un solo registro.....de qué tabla?

Comment: Buenos Dias, nesecito borrar  el idcliente,nombre y apellido de la tabla cliente pero no me deja borrarlo porque esta relacionado con la tabla ubicacion

Comment: bueno, pues qué quieres que pase con el registro de la tabla ubicación que tiene el idcliente que estás borrando?

Comment: ese tambien lo deseo borrar, que borre todos los registros que esten relacionados con el idcliente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder lograr esto debes ir borrando en orden (a menos que decidas que tus llaves foráneas sean en cascada). Primero debes borrar las filas correspondientes de la tabla `venta`, luego de la tabla `ubicacion` y finalmente de la tabla `cliente`:

```
DECLARE @idcliente varchar(50);
SET @idcliente = 'algún idcliente válido';

DELETE v
FROM dbo.venta v
INNER JOIN dbo.ubicacion u 
    ON v.fkubicacion = u.idubicacion
INNER JOIN dbo.cliente c
    ON u.fkcliente = c.idcliente
WHERE c.idcliente = @idcliente
;

DELETE u
FROM dbo.ubicacion u 
INNER JOIN dbo.cliente c
    ON u.fkcliente = c.idcliente
WHERE c.idcliente = @idcliente
;

DELETE FROM dbo.cliente
WHERE idcliente = @idcliente
;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho hay alguna forma de hacerlo de modo grafico para que sea mas sencillo?

Comment: @SneiderMuñoz a qué te refieres con hacerlo "de modo gráfico"?

Comment: hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin hacer un query, de ir directamente a los datos y borrarlos?

Comment: Hay formas de hacerlo, pero no te lo recomiendo, es demasiado fácil de cometer un error irreversible. De todas formas, te insto a que revises sobre llaves foráneas con condiciones en cascada si crees que el código es demasiado grande (y leas bien de sus ventajas y desventajas)

Comment: bueno Muchas Gracias me sirvio de mucho.